# How to add page number in pdf on to left corner

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I tried with the following code , Form number is added left side of the document but not at the top left corner.

```
document.open();

        Chunk number = new Chunk(formNo);
        number.setHorizontalScaling(1f);
        Paragraph pp = new Paragraph();
        pp.add(number);
        document.add(pp);
```

My proble is resolved when I added this simple alignment

document.open();

```
        Chunk number = new Chunk(formNo);
        number.setHorizontalScaling(1f);
        Paragraph pp = new Paragraph();
        pp.add(number);
        pp.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        document.add(pp);
```

Comment: How is this not "per the requirement"? What requirements?

Comment: my requirement is I will get a pdf form number from salesforce that  should be aligned to the top left corner of the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The top-left corner of the document has the following coordinates:

```
float x = document.getLeft();
float y = document.getTop();
```

If you want to add a number in the top-left corner, you need to do something like this:

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
     Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
     new Phrase(String.format("%d", writer.getPageNumber())),
     x - 10, y - 22, 0);
```

Not that I introduced a small horizontal margin of 10 user units.
I also subtracted 22 from the `y` value because the default font is 12 pt, and I want to make sure that there's sufficient space vertically to show the text.